# Can you update contribution history using git if you are pushing to bitbucket?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

My company uses bitbucket and for aesthetic and also I want to show my acivity for future roles want my contribution tab that shows commits to be updated (with the green squares). I push a lot but all my work is through bitbucket so it does not show up in github.

I wanted to know if git caches my pushes and can I use git somehow to have my commits show up on github. Not the content but that I did commit and am "active."

I feel like github does something like this, unless it tallys your pushes based on remote locations that end in github.com?

I tried to google this but couldn't find anything first glance.

Comment: The activity GitHub shows is based on what's happening on GitHub only. It has no way of seeing whatever you might be doing elsewhere.